# OpenUI5 / SAPUI5: Get Data from REST and display it in List

Tags: xml, rest, sapui5

I want to get data from a REST API. This worked so far but I can't display the list with my XML view...

**controller.js**

```
onInit: function () {
    var oContactModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    oContactModel.loadData(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/contacts", null, true, 'GET'
    );

    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oContactModel, "restContacts");
};
```

**view.xml**

```
<List id="contactList" width="auto" items="{restContacts>/}">
    <items>
        <ObjectListItem
            title="{restContacts>/name}"
            type="Navigation"
            press="onPressContact"
        />
    </items>
</List>
```

When I print the model from controller to console it shows me the data. But when I want to access the data in my XML view nothing happens...
The data from REST looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Thomas123",
        "registrationToken": "laksjdhoi",
        "available": true
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Thomas123",
        "registrationToken": "laksjdhoi",
        "available": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slash aka `/` usually indicates accessing the root level of your data strucuture.

With `/name` the parsing engine tries to find something like `jsondata.name`

What you want is `jsondata[n].name` (where `n` is the index of the contact in the array).

Omit the slash and the engine looks for `name` in the *current element* and not the root element

```
<ObjectListItem
    title="{restContacts>name}"
    type="Navigation"
    press="onPressContact"
/>
```

Working example: https://jsbin.com/bitehe/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks, i tried it but on my case it does not work... when i set the data locally (from file or like you) it works nice. But when i want to get the data over my rest api it does not work. I checked over the console of browser the objects. When i use the local data i've got in the model "aBinding" and "oData" with the data. When "debug" the rest object i've got "oData" with the right content but "aBinding" is empty... maybe this is wrong? I dont know...

Comment: I changed your example to get data from rest:
https://jsbin.com/xazobowaye/edit?html,output
It does not work... but why?

Comment: JSBin doesn't like `http`. Either prefix your URL with `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` (e. g. `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`) or replace `http` with `https` (but then you have to open the service once in Chrome and allow the unsecure connection)

Comment: Mhh okay now i'm confused... I use the same code but it does not work. When i echo the output to console i can see all objects correctly... Can i echo in view my model, like console.log() or like var_dump?

Comment: Ok, i found the mistake... i used loadData(URL, null, true, "GET")... without "null, true, GET" it works... thanks for your help anyway :)